# Need to take backup of log files and zip it when the last log file is overwritten by FileHandler

Tags: java, java.util.logging

My log file creation code is as follows:

```
public static final int FILE_SIZE = 512 * 1024;

public static void setup() throws SecurityException, IOException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    try {
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("/data/mcmlog", FILE_SIZE, 10, true);
        handler.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(handler);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warning("Failed to initialize logger handler.");
    }
}
```

It creates log file from mcmlog.0 to mcmlog.9 in cyclic manner. I have to zip these log files when mcmlog.9 is about to be overwritten by mcmlog.8 . How to find when mcmlog.9 is about to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find when mcmlog.9 is about to be overwritten.

Currently the only way to listen for when the FileHandler rotates is to extend [FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) and override the [protected void setOutputStream(OutputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html#setOutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) method.  FileHandler level is set to OFF during the rotation.

Here is an example class:

```
    public class ZipFileHandler extends FileHandler {
        private long rotated;
        private final long count;

        public ZipFileHandler(String p, long size, long count, boolean append) throws IOException {
            super(p, size, count, append);
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        protected synchronized void setOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws SecurityException {
            try {
                if (Level.OFF.equals(super.getLevel())) { //Rotating...
                    if (rotated++ != 0 && rotated % count == 0) {
                        zipFiles();
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                super.setOutputStream(out);
            }
        }

        private void zipFiles() {
            //...
        }
    }
```

You may run into a problem with file locking using that solution.  In which case you should build out a [proxy handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522010/how-to-create-a-rollback-log-which-generates-automatically-after-each-day-using/63568668#63568668) to deal with opening and closing the FileHandler.